# How to get maximum value and id using Max aggregation by country in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Getting maximum value by country but I want additional information for maximum value id. I tried many ways but I don't know how to fetch.

{

```
"aggs" : {
    "country_groups" : {
        "terms" : { "field" : "country.keyword",
                "size":30000
        },
      "aggs":{

            "max_price":{
            "max": { "field" : "video_count"}
           }

        }
```

}
    }

}

Comment: I want maximum value id also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the type of your `id` field (numeric or string), you have two ways of doing it.

If you look at the query below, if your `id` is numeric you can do the same as you did with `video_count`, i.e. using the `max` metric aggregation (see `max_id_num`).

However, if your `id` field is a string, you can leverage the `top_hits` aggregation and sort it in `descending` order (see `max_id_str`).

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "country_groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "country.keyword",
        "size": 30000
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_price_and_id": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {
              "video_count": "desc"
            },
            "_source": ["channel_id", "video_count"]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Expected numeric type on field [channel_id], but got [text]"

Comment: So since your id field is of type text you can remove the `max_id_num` aggregation. Check my updated answer

Comment: this query getting channel_id but that channel_id is not for maximum channel_id

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... The query returns the maximum channel_id per country. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: this query return the minimum value id per country

Comment: Can you share an example of what you get vs what you expect instead?

Comment: "key": "VN",
                    "doc_count": 1673,
                    "max_price": {
                        "value": 13947
                    } "_source": {
                                        "channel_id": "UCzyhaftywTbvKeu3fgakJ6g"
                                    },
                                    "sort": [
                                        "UCzyhaftywTbvKeu3fgakJ6g"

Comment: the maximum value is 13947 but the channel id is not for this value id

Comment: Oh ok, got it, you want the channel_id of the document with the max video_count...

Comment: Thank you for your support this query working perfect